# get parent's siblings of term in views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I want to create a views that termId passed from url to it  and then show parent and parent's siblings(uncle aunt) of that term,,I can handle that show parent term id ,but I don't any idea that how can I get parent's siblings,I can handle it finally with `php_views` but first ask here maybe somebody has better solution.

**tnx for your attetions**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some a quick search and stumbled onto [this comment in this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1084338#comment-8426339), which led to the [Views arg parent term module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_arg_parent_term). From what I read on the module page

*..this module provides another default plugin argument, to get
associated parent terms.*

I think it can be helpful in your case.